# Keep same archive.php for post from archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have create a new template for my archive ( using archive.php);

however, when I click to the post from my archive list, it keep the same layout of the single_post,

I'd like the post open from the archive to keep the same layout of this archive.php

Do you know what has to be the process to realize this ?

```
?php
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'meta_key' => 'super_post_views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); /*,  'tag' => featured*/
query_posts( $args );
$i=0;
while(have_posts()): the_post();
?>
```

this code is one part of the new layout from the archive.php

I suppose it must be link from this line:

```
while(have_posts()): the_post();
```

and call a new single_post template, I don't really know, what do you suggest ?

I've also create a new archive_type by calling the function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'archive_post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'archive_post' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'archive_post' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

but I don't know how to link it.

Comment: You should never use `query_posts`, use the `pre_get_posts` filter if you want to change what WordPress loads, otherwise you're doubling the work being done and causing other issues. Also can you indicate the filenames of all the relevant files ( e.g. your new archive template )

Comment: Hi,I'm trying to call by the query `'post_type' => 'archive_post'` but it doesn't work.

The first code I have add is in the `archive.php` where my post are listed in a template I have build;

I have build a new post_template by the function ( last code I have added) call `archive-archive_post.php` , I'd like the post template call from the `archive.php` to use this new template `archive-archive_post.php`

Im going to change to get `pre_get_post`, but how can i do for my primary question ?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: So if we ignore everything that you've done and go back to the very beginning, what are you trying to do? Create a listing of posts? Change the order of posts in an archive?